clone with curved Text not working in fabric.js version 5.3.0
I'm working with fabric.js version 5.3.0.
I want to clone curve text and add to canvas.
Description:
clone not working with curved text , it not return clone object same as original one.
Please check below fiddle to generate the issue.
https://jsfiddle.net/Niketa_patel/snw9yx21/7/
here is my code:


(function (fabric) {
  /*
   * CurvedText object for fabric.js
   * @author Arjan Haverkamp (av01d)
   * @date January 2018
   */

  fabric.CurvedText = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Object, {
    type: "curved-text",
    diameter: 250,
    kerning: 0,
    text: "",
    flipped: false,
    fill: "#000",
    fontFamily: "Times New Roman",
    fontSize: 24, // in px
    fontWeight: "normal",
    fontStyle: "", // "normal", "italic" or "oblique".
    cacheProperties: fabric.Object.prototype.cacheProperties.concat(
      "diameter",
      "kerning",
      "flipped",
      "fill",
      "fontFamily",
      "fontSize",
      "fontWeight",
      "fontStyle",
      "strokeStyle",
      "strokeWidth"
    ),
    strokeStyle: null,
    strokeWidth: 0,

    initialize: function (text, options) {
      options || (options = {});
      if (typeof text === 'object' && text.text) {
        this.text = text.text;
        text =  this.text;
      } else {
        this.text = text;
      }

      this.callSuper("initialize", options);
      this.set("lockUniScaling", true);

      // Draw curved text here initially too, while we need to know the width and height.
      var canvas = this.getCircularText();
      this._trimCanvas(canvas);
      this.set("width", canvas.width);
      this.set("height", canvas.height);
    },

    _getFontDeclaration: function () {
      return [
        // node-canvas needs "weight style", while browsers need "style weight"
        fabric.isLikelyNode ? this.fontWeight : this.fontStyle,
        fabric.isLikelyNode ? this.fontStyle : this.fontWeight,
        this.fontSize + "px",
        fabric.isLikelyNode ? '"' + this.fontFamily + '"' : this.fontFamily,
      ].join(" ");
    },

    _trimCanvas: function (canvas) {
      try {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
          w = canvas.width,
          h = canvas.height,
          pix = {
            x: [],
            y: [],
          },
          n,
          imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h),
          fn = function (a, b) {
            return a - b;
          };

        for (var y = 0; y < h; y++) {
          for (var x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            if (imageData.data[(y * w + x) * 4 + 3] > 0) {
              pix.x.push(x);
              pix.y.push(y);
            }
          }
        }
        pix.x.sort(fn);
        pix.y.sort(fn);
        n = pix.x.length - 1;

        w = pix.x[n] - pix.x[0];
        h = pix.y[n] - pix.y[0];
        var cut = ctx.getImageData(pix.x[0], pix.y[0], w, h);

        canvas.width = w;
        canvas.height = h;
        ctx.putImageData(cut, 0, 0);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    },

    // Source: http://jsfiddle.net/rbdszxjv/
    getCircularText: function () {
      // debugger;
      var text = this.text,
        diameter = this.diameter,
        flipped = this.flipped,
        kerning = this.kerning,
        fill = this.fill,
        inwardFacing = true,
        startAngle = 0,
        canvas = fabric.util.createCanvasElement(),
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
        cw, // character-width
        x, // iterator
        clockwise = -1; // draw clockwise for aligned right. Else Anticlockwise
      if (flipped) {
        startAngle = 180;
        inwardFacing = false;
      }

      startAngle *= Math.PI / 180; // convert to radians

      // Calc heigt of text in selected font:
      var d = document.createElement("div");
      d.style.position = "relative";
      d.style.zIndex = 1111111111111;
      d.style.fontFamily = this.fontFamily;
      d.style.whiteSpace = "nowrap";
      d.style.fontSize = this.fontSize + "px";
      d.style.fontWeight = this.fontWeight;
      d.style.fontStyle = this.fontStyle;
      d.textContent = text;
      document.body.appendChild(d);
      var textHeight = d.offsetHeight;
      document.body.removeChild(d);

      canvas.width = canvas.height = diameter;

      ctx.font = this._getFontDeclaration();

      // Reverse letters for center inward.
      if (inwardFacing) {
        text = text.split("").reverse().join("");
      }

      // Setup letters and positioning
      ctx.translate(diameter / 2, diameter / 2); // Move to center
      startAngle += Math.PI * !inwardFacing; // Rotate 180 if outward
      ctx.textBaseline = "middle"; // Ensure we draw in exact center
      ctx.textAlign = "center"; // Ensure we draw in exact center

      // rotate 50% of total angle for center alignment
      for (x = 0; x < text.length; x++) {
        cw = ctx.measureText(text[x]).width;
        startAngle +=
          ((cw + (x == text.length - 1 ? 0 : kerning)) /
            (diameter / 2 - textHeight) /
            2) *
          -clockwise;
      }

      // Phew... now rotate into final start position
      ctx.rotate(startAngle);

      // Now for the fun bit: draw, rotate, and repeat
      for (x = 0; x < text.length; x++) {
        cw = ctx.measureText(text[x]).width; // half letter
        // rotate half letter
        ctx.rotate((cw / 2 / (diameter / 2 - textHeight)) * clockwise);
        // draw the character at "top" or "bottom"
        // depending on inward or outward facing

        // Stroke
        if (this.strokeStyle && this.strokeWidth) {
          ctx.strokeStyle = this.strokeStyle;
          ctx.lineWidth = this.strokeWidth;
          ctx.miterLimit = 2;
          ctx.strokeText(
            text[x],
            0,
            (inwardFacing ? 1 : -1) * (0 - diameter / 2 + textHeight / 2)
          );
        }

        // Actual text
        ctx.fillStyle = fill;
        ctx.fillText(
          text[x],
          0,
          (inwardFacing ? 1 : -1) * (0 - diameter / 2 + textHeight / 2)
        );

        ctx.rotate(
          ((cw / 2 + kerning) / (diameter / 2 - textHeight)) * clockwise
        ); // rotate half letter
      }
      return canvas;
    },

    // Curve Text Cloned
    getCircularTextCalculations: function () {
      let curvCalculations = {};

      var text = this.text,
        diameter = this.diameter,
        flipped = this.flipped,
        kerning = this.kerning,
        fill = this.fill,
        inwardFacing = true,
        startAngle = 0,
        canvas = fabric.util.createCanvasElement(),
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
        cw, // character-width
        x, // iterator
        clockwise = -1; // draw clockwise for aligned right. Else Anticlockwise
      if (flipped) {
        startAngle = 180;
        inwardFacing = false;
      }
      startAngle *= Math.PI / 180; // convert to radians

      let initialize = {
        text,
        diameter,
        flipped,
        kerning,
        fill,
        inwardFacing,
        startAngle,
        canvas,
        ctx,
        cw,
        x,
        clockwise,
        inwardFacing,
      };

      curvCalculations = { ...curvCalculations, initialize };

      // Calc heigt of text in selected font:
      var d = document.createElement("div");
      d.style.position = "relative";
      d.style.zIndex = 1111111111111;
      d.style.fontFamily = this.fontFamily;
      d.style.whiteSpace = "nowrap";
      d.style.fontSize = this.fontSize + "px";
      d.style.fontWeight = this.fontWeight;
      d.style.fontStyle = this.fontStyle;
      d.textContent = text;
      document.body.appendChild(d);
      var textHeight = d.offsetHeight;
      document.body.removeChild(d);

      canvas.width = canvas.height = diameter;

      ctx.font = this._getFontDeclaration();

      // Reverse letters for center inward.
      if (inwardFacing) {
        text = text.split("").reverse().join("");
      }

      let fontCalculations = {
        fontSize: this.fontSize,
        fontWeight: this.fontWeight,
        fontStyle: this.fontStyle,
        textHeight,
        _getFontDeclaration: this._getFontDeclaration(),
      };

      curvCalculations = { ...curvCalculations, fontCalculations };

      // Setup letters and positioning
      ctx.translate(diameter / 2, diameter / 2); // Move to center
      startAngle += Math.PI * !inwardFacing; // Rotate 180 if outward
      ctx.textBaseline = "middle"; // Ensure we draw in exact center
      ctx.textAlign = "center"; // Ensure we draw in exact center

      // rotate 50% of total angle for center alignment
      for (x = 0; x < text.length; x++) {
        cw = ctx.measureText(text[x]).width;
        startAngle +=
          ((cw + (x == text.length - 1 ? 0 : kerning)) /
            (diameter / 2 - textHeight) /
            2) *
          -clockwise;
      }

      // Phew... now rotate into final start position
      ctx.rotate(startAngle);

      let ctxRotateFirstLoop = {
        startAngle,
      };

      curvCalculations = { ...curvCalculations, ctxRotateFirstLoop };

      let drawRotateLoopCalc = {};
      let rotate1 = [];
      let ctxStrikeText = [];
      let ctxFillText = [];
      let ctxRotate = [];
      // Now for the fun bit: draw, rotate, and repeat
      for (x = 0; x < text.length; x++) {

        cw = ctx.measureText(text[x]).width; // half letter
        // rotate half letter
        ctx.rotate((cw / 2 / (diameter / 2 - textHeight)) * clockwise);
        rotate1 = [...rotate1, (cw / 2 / (diameter / 2 - textHeight)) * clockwise]

        // draw the character at "top" or "bottom"
        // depending on inward or outward facing

        // Stroke
        if (this.strokeStyle && this.strokeWidth) {
          ctx.strokeStyle = this.strokeStyle;
          ctx.lineWidth = this.strokeWidth;
          ctx.miterLimit = 2;
          ctx.strokeText(
            text[x],
            0,
            (inwardFacing ? 1 : -1) * (0 - diameter / 2 + textHeight / 2)
          );
        }

        ctxStrikeText = [...ctxStrikeText, (inwardFacing ? 1 : -1) * (0 - diameter / 2 + textHeight / 2)]


        // Actual text
        ctx.fillStyle = fill;
        ctx.fillText(
          text[x],
          0,
          (inwardFacing ? 1 : -1) * (0 - diameter / 2 + textHeight / 2)
        );

        ctxFillText = [...ctxFillText, (inwardFacing ? 1 : -1) * (0 - diameter / 2 + textHeight / 2)]


        ctx.rotate(
          ((cw / 2 + kerning) / (diameter / 2 - textHeight)) * clockwise
        ); // rotate half letter
        
        ctxRotate = [...ctxRotate, ((cw / 2 + kerning) / (diameter / 2 - textHeight)) * clockwise]

      }
      
      

      drawRotateLoopCalc = {
        rotate1,
        ctxStrikeText,
        ctxFillText,
        ctxRotate
      }
      curvCalculations = { ...curvCalculations, drawRotateLoopCalc };
      return curvCalculations;
    },

    _set: function (key, value) {
      switch (key) {
        /* case 'scaleX':
          this.fontSize *= value;
          this.diameter *= value;
          this.width *= value;
          this.scaleX = 1;
          if (this.width < 1) {
            this.width = 1;
          }
          break;
 */
        /* case 'scaleY':
          this.height *= value;
          this.scaleY = 1;
          if (this.height < 1) {
            this.height = 1;
          }
          break; */

        default:
          this.callSuper("_set", key, value);
          break;
      }
    },

    _render: function (ctx) {
      var canvas = this.getCircularText();
      this._trimCanvas(canvas);

      this.set("width", canvas.width);
      this.set("height", canvas.height);

      ctx.drawImage(
        canvas,
        -this.width / 2,
        -this.height / 2,
        this.width,
        this.height
      );

      this.setCoords();
    },

    toObject: function (propertiesToInclude) {
      return this.callSuper(
        "toObject",
        [
          "text",
          "diameter",
          "kerning",
          "flipped",
          "fill",
          "fontFamily",
          "fontSize",
          "fontWeight",
          "fontStyle",
          "strokeStyle",
          "strokeWidth",
          "width"
        ].concat(propertiesToInclude)
      );
    },
  });

  fabric.CurvedText.fromObject = function (object, callback, forceAsync) {
    return fabric.Object._fromObject(
      "CurvedText",
      object,
      callback,
      forceAsync,
      "curved-text"
    );
  };
})(typeof fabric !== "undefined" ? fabric : fabric);
var fcanvas = new fabric.Canvas('canv');

   const curvedText = new fabric.CurvedText('It feels so nice to be able to draw', {
        diameter: 360,
        fontSize: 32,
        fontFamily: 'Arial',
        left: 50,
        top: 50,
        fill: 'red'
    });
  let democopy = {};
   
    // Add a circular text
    fcanvas.add(curvedText);
  curvedText.clone(cloned=>{
  console.log(cloned,'curvedText');
  democopy = cloned;
  })
  democopy.clone(cloned=>{
  console.log(cloned,'cloned');
  console.log(curvedText,'curvedText')
  fcanvas.add(cloned);
  })
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/5.3.1/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canv" width="500" height="300" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); width: 400px; height: 400px; -webkit-user-select: none;"></canvas>



Thank you :)

Put your styles in an object and re-apply them with set().
const curvedTextStyle = {
    diameter: 360,
    fontSize: 32,
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    left: 50,
    top: 50,
    fill: 'red'
};
const curvedText = new fabric.CurvedText('It feels so nice to be able to draw', curvedTextStyle);
let democopy = {};

fcanvas.add(curvedText);
curvedText.clone(cloned=>{
  cloned.set(curvedTextStyle);
  democopy = cloned;
  fcanvas.add(democopy);
});

